Docker networking, I do not understand this way of access the docker host machine from the container
I have a docker container, started with the default bridged network, info:
"Networks": {
    "bridge": {
            ... 
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }

Within this container, I use host.docker.internal hostname to resolve the ip of my docker host machine, it resolves to 192.168.65.254 and ping answers
I also use in this container:
nc -zv host.docker.internal 7159

to prove that I am accessing my docker host. If I run this service on 7159 of the docker host the netcat returns "succeeded!" when I stop this service on 7159 of the docker host netcat returns "failed: Connection refused"
Question
I do not understand how this ip connectivity is possible. On my docker host there is no such interface which is configured to be on 192.168.65.254 address and there is no interface on 192.168.65 subnet. My docker host's has a physical interface which is on 192.168.1.2 on a 255.255.255.0 subnet. There are plenty of other virtual interfaces for HyperV and VirtualBox etc on the docker host.
I do know that docker uses virtual networking, but I suppose both the OS in the container and the OS of the docker host should see an interface and the virtual routing must be implemented somehow.
On the container I see using ip a command, which is OK, one it the loopbacke the other is the default docker bridged network:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: eth0@if35: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
 link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet 172.17.0.3/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

So I do not understand where is this mystic 192.168.65 subnet, and its 192.168.65.254 host is defined and accessible?

The IP connectivity is possible because Docker internally maps host.docker.internal to 192.168.65.254 using its own DNS and routing mechanisms.
This IP is virtual and managed by Docker, not tied to any physical network interface on the host. Docker handles the routing internally, allowing containers to communicate with the host without needing a corresponding host interface in the 192.168.65.0/24 subnet.
